# Count elements in numpy array between bounds

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array such that:

```
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6])
```

I want to know the frequency of values >=0 & <1, >=1 & <2, >=2 & <3...etc

so I would get an new array like:

```
freq =[2,3,2,5,2,5,1].
```

I can use np.where((arr>=0)&(arr<1)) but this changes the shape of arr. Is there a pythonic way of getting the frequency of values over an interval of 1?

Comment: Do you actually have integers and single integer intervals? Because `np.bincount` is likely all you need in that case. If not, `np.histogram`.

Comment: the interval range will be integer as in the question but the values in arr may be either floats or integers

Comment: Then `np.histogram(arr, bins=7, range=(0, 7))` for instance.

Comment: so for clarity, this is inclusive of the lower limit but not the upper limit, correct? so for example >=0 & < 1

Comment: Yep, as noted in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).